# Where can I buy lugs for a classic roadster frame geometry?

Tags: framebuilding

The title says it all. I want to build my own frame and need lugs that will fit the roadster (e.g. Raleigh Tourist) geometry.

Comment: try ceeway.com they appear to have what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "roadster geometry" you mean a slack (66-68 degree) head tube and seat tube angle I think you might be out of luck for anything commercially produced. The cost of creating a wide variety of investment castings and distributing the product is high and the demand is minuscule.  You might look into TIG-welded custom lugs, such as those made by [ANT bikes](http://antbikemike.wordpress.com/frame-building-classes/one-week-class/) or by Mark Nobilette as described in [Bicycle Quarterly vol. 4 no. 4](http://www.bikequarterly.com/BuildersSpeak.html). [This ANT-built bike](http://antbikemike.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/john-wc-001.jpg) appears to be an example of a roadster geometry frame using custom lugs. Most of the examples of bicycles I've seen in this style appear to have just very simple tubular lugs rather than anything particularly fancy.

Comment: Does this really answer the question asked?

Comment: I can reword it, but I'm trying to state that you probably can't "buy" such lugs, though you could possibly have them made.  If you've got a suggestion that makes that clearer I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: TIG welded lugs are a bit ridiculous. If that's what you want, just TIG the frame. My only point was that this is more comment than answer.

Comment: Even tubular lugs are usually cast, and the shaping can be done with hand filing, as long as enough material is left for brazing.

Comment: [ANT bikes](http://antbikemike.wordpress.com/frame-building-classes/one-week-class/) TIG-welds custom lugs for their framebuilding class. Even a non-bicycle TIG welder should be able to make an effective steel lug to your specification, if that's what you're looking for. Suggesting that the OP browse through lists of lugs they've likely been through seems like less of an answer yet.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right, it's exactly the geometry I am looking for. The links you posted help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The best place I've found is [Henry James Bicycle supply](http://www.henryjames.com/). They make frame building jigs, and supply most boutique US based frame builders.

[Ceeway](http://ceeway.com/) is a good choice in Europe.

Some lugs may need to be custom cast, or modified, depending on the head tube and seat tube angles you choose. The fork rake will need to be fairly slack to match that style.

Comment: The [Henry James 2012 price list](http://www.henryjames.com/price10.pdf) shows only lugs in the 73-74 degree HTA range.  [Kirk Frameworks](http://www.kirkframeworks.com/blog/2010/05/05/lugs-mitering-and-experts/) claims the ability to modify a lug up to about 2.5 degrees, which wouldn't get to the slack geometry of a Raleigh Tourist.

Comment: Agreed. No one currently makes investment cast in that range (that I've found), which is why I suggested Henry James, who will custom cast lugs. Whether they will do so for a one off bike is unknown, but it's the best option I've seen. That said, lost wax casting is not that difficult a process to learn. To master, yes, but not to learn. Perhaps he should cast his own.

Answer (score 3):

No Roadster lugs are available for the independent or small shop. That is why I had to make them.

Roadster lugs are made [India, China, Taiwan and of course in the Netherlands], it is just that distributors like Nova and Ceeway do not buy them.

I find it amusing about the comment about TIG welding lugs. Why lug anything really...it is just for looks. Stamped lugs are ***welded*** together :)  Only the expensive racing lugs are cast.

I think you best bet is to try and find them in India or Taiwan and ask for a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Ceeway Bike Building Supplies](http://ceeway.com)

Comment: Reviewing the lugs available at ceeway.com, I couldn't find any that weren't designed for a 71-74 degree HTA/STA, which is not what the OP was asking for.  The question was not generically "where can I buy bicycle lugs".

Answer (score 1):

Nova Cycle Supply offers many framebuilding components including lugs. I can't speak to geometries.